# How do I change the main display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have a 22" display and a 19" display, the 19" is the default display, at the moment, how would I go about making the 22" display and work as how it should (Like how window's manages it) with the icons on the right display etc etc.. :)

Hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to specify which one you like in display preferences.  I had to drag them to the position I wanted them to be in, and click apply.

Comment: Problem is if I drag them into position how it's meant to work, it still does nothing, but instead of moving the cursor left, I would have to move it to the right to get the left display, which I would not want to do. Only thing I can think of is switching the dvi (22") with the vga (19") but other than that, I see no option what so ever on changing which is the default display, sadly. :L

Comment: Not at my computer right now I will look when I get home. See if I can figure it out I had the same problem.

Comment: Did you select apply after dragging the displays? The Displays settings is one of the few places where you have to click apply after making changes.